# Is there a way to copy a string of letters and numbers based on that string containing 3 specific letters, all found within a single cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that has a column, with each cell filled with pages of data stripped from a database. In each cell, 1 or 2 serial numbers may be defined. There are three known formats of serial numbers:
Starting with YV and are 10 digits long.
Starting with VNA and are 8 digits long.
Starting with SVNA and are 9 digits long.
I need to extract every copy of every serial number in that column out to a separate cell. There may be 0, 1, or 2 serial numbers in each cell, and the copied information needs to be left blank, left with a single serial number, or left with 2 serial numbers separated by a comma and a space ("VNA1234A, VNAB4321").

I don't have any code to suggest because all code I've seen in this vein is to extract an entire known word, rather than a whole word or phrase based on a few letters.

Is there some way to do this?

[image: Long text in work notes field]

I'd like the serial number VNA3FB00 from the text in the picture to be copied into the F cell to the left. And if there was another serial number, to have that copied as well.

Comment: Please do share a screenshot (or rather some sample markdown data) which includes your input and desired output. For help, see [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Also, what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: added the picture and a brief description to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with a formula and access to `TEXTJOIN` (available in O365 and Excel 2019). In `F2` the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G1,":"," "),","," "),"."," "),";"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'YV') and string-length(.) =10 or starts-with(., 'VNA') and string-length(.) =8 or starts-with(., 'SVNA') and string-length(.) =9]"))
```

[image]

You may need to add more substitutions in depending on how your data looks.

---

You could also decide to go with an UDF through VBA. Maybe something along these lines:

```
Function REGEX(str As String, pat As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = pat
    If .Test(str) = True Then
        For Each Mtch In .Execute(str)
            If REGEX = "" Then
                REGEX = Mtch
            Else
                REGEX = REGEX & ", " & Mtch
            End If
        Next
    End If
End With

End Function
```

You can call this function in `F2`, through:

```
=REGEX(G2,"\b(?:YV[^\W_]{8}|S?VNA[^\W_]{5})\b")
```

Where you may want to sway `[^\W_]` for `[A-Z0-9]` if you want to exclude lowercase letters to.

If you are unfamiliar with regular expressions then have a look at the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zfrTlq/3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/9758194) introductary post on regex within VBA.

---

[image]

Comment: That seems to work for some of the values, but most of them are being missed, and instead of a blank cell, it's showing #VALUE! I'd do another screenshot, but I think that wouldn't show the reason. I suspect there are some odd formatting issues with the cells in column G.

"2020-03-24 15:47:46 - (Work notes)
Monitor, wired keyboard/mouse
SVNA3L3A0


picked up equipment

2020-03-16 08:51:04 - (Work notes)
Hello,

I see that the monitor part of your ticket is incomplete. Update me with this information."

Comment: For you own sanity I'd use the UDF =) @takieda.

Comment: The above contains a straight copy and paste of a G cell that ended with "#VALUE!" in the F cell. I don't know if that's going to have the same effect on your end though.
In fact, having copy/pasted it back into the excel spreadsheet suddenly allowed it to work.

Comment: If I copy that into `G2` both the formula *and* UDF show the correct corresponding serialnumber @takieda

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with UDF - definitions online range from United Dairy Farmers to Universal Disk Format.

Comment: Excel would let you create your own *user defined* functions (or short UDF). You can then use these functions along with the build-in functions. Also `#Value` is the error when the suggested formula won't retrieve any valid import through `FILTERXML`. A simple `IFERROR` will deal with that.

Comment: Thank you. I will work with this and see what I can figure out. I'm just starting to learn this stuff.

Comment: As a [starting point](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-create-custom-excel-functions/) @takieda. Instead of the code they tell you to copy, copy the code I gave you. Btw, you have chosen a rather tough usecase to start of with =)

Comment: using VBA and the REGEX call worked perfectly. I think there are formatting issues with Column G that disallow the original code you posted to work. I will test some stuff later to determine if that's true. Thank you very much for your help, JvdV!